# Weekly Topic Challenge: Call for Proposals

Tags: discussion, weekly-topic-challenge

This is the call for proposals for the weekly topic challenge. Topic proposals should be along the lines of the [ideas proposed here](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/411/20), although you can branch out from those criteria if you make a convincing argument.

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on.
How does it work?

- Please post your proposals as questions on this meta site.

  - Each such question should

    - be tagged topic-challenge-proposal and discussion;
    - explain the topic;
    - optionally, link to existing questions or tags on the topic; and
    - optionally, argue for its adoption.
  - Answers to such a question can argue for or against its topic's adoption.
- Upvote topics you'd like to see; downvote those you wouldn't.
- Each week, probably Wednesday or Thursday, I will choose from among the proposed topics, and the challenge will begin: thinking of and posting good questions in the main site on that topic. (In choosing from among the proposed topics, I will take the votes and seasonality into consideration.)

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How can I be notified of new challenges?

- Check back on Meta from time to time, particularly on Wednesday or Thursday, to see if there's a newly edited weekly-topic-challenge post.
- Check Meta's weekly-topic-challenge tag to see only the posts in the challenge (with the current challenge at the top of the list), or check Meta's featured tag to see all meta posts announcing currently-relevant site features and events (including the current challenge).
- To see just the current challenge, use [this search](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekly-topic-challenge+featured).
- If you use a blog-reader or otherwise follow RSS feeds, you can add the [feeds](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=weekly-topic-challenge&sort=newest) for weekly-topic-challenge or featured to your reader and automatically get updates soon after they're posted.

Comment: I'm confused - should proposals be "Answers to this question" or "questions on this meta site"?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, @Standback, then you write your proposal here on Meta as a question and additionally add an answer to this call of proposals here, which links to your Meta-question. Short answer: Both!

Comment: It looks like this call was modelled on the one from Judaism.SE, which just changed from "post proposals as answers here" to "post proposals under this new tag".  I recommend one or the other but not both.  (Given the tag you can get to all the questions, after all; you don't need to link them from here.)

Answer (score 1):

#### Topics

- Week of 8 February 2012: [Collaboration](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/wtcs-collaboration)
- Week of 15 February 2012: [Short stories](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/wtcs-short-story-writing)