# WTCS: Collaboration

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge-proposal, weekly-topic-challenge

**This has been chosen for the week of 8 February 2012 to 14 Feburary, 2012**

---

Weekly topic challenge suggestion: Collaboration.  Questions about:

- Working with co-authors -- division of labor, managing the work, workflows, etc
- Working with subject-matter experts -- asking the right questions, getting the most out of the consultation, etc
- "People" issues, if all collaborators aren't equal partners -- mentoring, helping each person shine, quality control, etc.

Working alone can be very different from working with others, whether you're writing a novel, technical documentation, articles, or scripts.

Comment: Yes, yes, many times a yes! I've collaborated as a writer with a handful of people and, oof, it has gone exceptionally well and exceptionally poorly. Round-robin stories are by far the hardest. a good example of a collab story that went *astonishingly* well might be [MTCFF ULTRA](http://mtcffultra.com/). Though older, it brought together an array of people from across multiple fandoms/genres.

Comment: @Aarthi, you don't actually have to wait for the challenge to ask questions on the topic, you know.  Fire away. :-)

Comment: haha, true true. What I *should* do is use my old fandom connections and push them to use this site.

Comment: Great subject. Let me just add that I think the weekly topic is a great idea, look forward to more!

Answer (score 4):

Winner with 10 up-votes:
[How do you avoid the problem of a collaborative work having separate voices?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/how-do-you-avoid-the-problem-of-a-collaborative-work-having-separate-voices)

---

Questions on the Challenge Topic:

- [How do you track dependencies for your co-authors?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4976/how-do-you-track-dependencies-for-your-co-authors)
- [How do collaborating authors choose an agent?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4983/how-do-collaborating-authors-choose-an-agent)
- [How does collaboration affect a publishing contract?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5001/how-does-collaboration-affect-a-publishing-contract)
- [How do co-authors' rights to a manuscript work?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-do-co-authors-rights-to-a-manuscript-work)
- [How can I keep up with my co-author's detail creation?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5024/how-can-i-keep-up-with-my-co-authors-detail-creation)
- [What exercises will help me write my co-author's character?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5026/what-exercises-will-help-me-write-my-co-authors-character)