# Answer keeps getting turned into a comment; help?

Tags: support, community-wiki, answers

I tried to add a community-wiki answer to [this week's challenge topic](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/wtcs-collaboration#autocomment735) to start a list of questions asked during the challenge week, but it turned my answer into a comment on the question instead.  (Twice before I noticed.)  Why is that?  Yes it's my "question", but I thought answering the "do you really want to answer your own question?" prompt appropriately would take care of that.  Is there something special about community wiki?

Comment: Hmmm. I tried as well, and was also converted to a comment. I got a note reading "Trivial answer automatically converted into comment." A non-CW wiki answer (with no links) did not have this problem. Editing the non-CW answer to add the links and mark as CW worked as a workaround.

Comment: I will look into if this is a recent change in the software or what's going on.  Thanks for flagging it.

Comment: @Standback, thanks for figuring out the work-around!

Comment: Why did you make it CW in the first place?

Comment: It's not really an answer but a community resource -- a list of all the questions for that challenge.  IMO CW communicates "edit me freely!" in a way that non-CW doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that adding an answer along those lines that is just links gets turned into a comment as desired behavior.  Not quite sure on the details of the system catching CW versus non-CW answers, but I believe this is expected.  For now we'll have to use Standback's workaround to get the lists posted.  Great idea on posting lists, by the way!

Comment: Thanks for looking into it!  I didn't come up with the idea of posting the lists; Judaism.SE has been doing that from the beginning and I've found it helpful.