# WTCS: Short story writing

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge-proposal, weekly-topic-challenge

**This has been chosen for the week of 15 February 2012 to 21 Feburary 2012**

---

Short story writing is an art form in itself. Short stories can range from six words, all the way to several thousand words. They're often concise snapshots of the human condition, and can be welcome, satisfying reads in these days of short attention spans. For the author, too, they can be seen as gateways to getting yourself into print, and getting yourself noticed.

However, Writers.SE has a grand total of [19 questions tagged short-story](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-story). It's time this was rectified! So I propose we have a topic challenge on short stories, trying to dissect this art form and provide good, solid advice on how to plan them, write them, and publish them.

Answer (score 2):

Questions contributed for this topic challenge:

- [What marketing techniques are effective for short story ebook collections?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5045/what-marketing-techniques-are-effective-for-short-story-ebook-collections)
- [Do I need to know anything to write a short story that I wouldn't know by studying how to write novels?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5054/do-i-need-to-know-anything-to-write-a-short-story-that-i-wouldnt-know-by-studyi)
- [What are the advantages to setting a word limit for a short story?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/what-word-limit-is-a-good-starting-point-for-writing-a-short-story)
- [How can I find short-story spinoffs for my fantasy epic?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5078/how-can-i-find-short-story-spinoffs-for-my-fantasy-epic)