# Does SE have a platform for poetry analysis?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I need help in analyzing poetic text and I was wondering if SE provides a platform for the same. Would it be fine if I post poetry analysis related topics on Writers SE or is there another place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poetry is on topic; however, analysis isn't really. While [Literature.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature) was active, poetry analysis was certainly on-topic there - but that site didn't get out of beta, and I'm afraid we're not a good alternative venue. Some cases might fit, but as a general purpose, I don't think poetry analysis is on topic. For two reasons:

**Analysis is a poor fit for SE sites.** SE uses a Q&A format; literary (and poetry) analysis does not fit comfortably into that format. Although they can prompt excellent responses, "Please analyze this poem" or "What do you think of my analysis of this poem" are rarely answerable questions. There is no possibility of an authoritative answer; all interpretations and additions can be valuable; most answers are entirely subjective. These are great conversations, but they aren't Q&A.

**Writers.SE is for *writing*, not for literary analysis.** If you're trying to capture a particular technique present in a poem, *in order to write your own work with it*, then analyzing an existing piece (with your own work-in-progress clearly in mind) is on topic. Analyzing literature or poetry "just" for the sake of appreciating them better isn't on-topic here. (It used to be on topic at [Literature.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature), but that site is, alas, defunct.)

There are a couple of obvious exceptions:

- Critique questions are tricky to pull off, but they're on-topic. So if you're *writing* poetry, and can shape a specific question you'd like analyzed/answered, then Writers.SE is fine for that.
- If your question is aimed at learning some specific aspect of writing technique, using existing pieces, that's on-topic. (See e.g. [some case study questions](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/is-this-attempt-at-a-case-study-question-something-wed-like-to-see-more-of/431#431).)

The overall guideline is: **have a clear, explicit, *specific* reason why your question is writing-related.** If you've got that, it's on-topic. If you don't, then IMHO it's off-topic here.

Comment: +1 and accept. Thanks for taking time and explaining it clearly.

Answer (score -2):

Looking at the FAQ, [poetry is on-topic here](https://writers.stackexchange.com/faq#whats-on-topic-here).

Comment: It says __writing__ poetry, not __analysis__ of it.

Comment: On that link, there is a mention that asking for a critique is on-topic. I think that is close enough to make your proposed post(s) on-topic.

Comment: @Tshepang - A critique is meant to help the author make a piece of writing better, which is not the case with literary analysis.

Comment: @NeilFein thanks; I was thinking they were basically the same